# Is my plumbing drain/vent setup ok?

Tags: plumbing, drain, vent

I'm new at plumbing, working on installing a master bath in our house. Pictured is the room with the shower pan in place, a vanity drawn where that will go and you can see the toilet flange sitting in between where the toilet will sit. Does the setup I've drawn look correct? Are there any mistakes that I need to change or a better way of doing anything. Under the room is unfinished basement. My cleanout needs to be pretty close to the toilet. I can't move it further left past the shower as there is a block wall there.
[image]

Comment: You may not need that cleanup there. I think a toilet opening “counts” for the same purpose. If you want to have a cleanout there because you have good access from the basement that is fine.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Nice diagram!

Comment: Shower drain may not get adequate air. Can you tie a vent stack from it to the toilet stack?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you are located and plumbing terminology can vary by region, however, the typical method to plumbing a single bathroom would be to use a 'wet vent'. I've discussed wet vents in this [previous answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/116736/wet-vent-distance-for-toilet-drain/116737#116737), which includes a full definition as well as the components of a wet vent.

One condition of a wet vent is that the toilet needs to be the last fixture connected (or be connected via a symmetrical fitting). Here's the reworking of your sketch as a wet vent with the toilet as the last fixture:

[image]

The portion highlighted in red is the wet vent. This section of pipe will drain the sink as well as allow air to pass through and vent both the shower and toilet. With this configuration, you do not need the second vent at the end.

As others have mentioned, the cleanout at the end is optional, as the removal of the toilet will act as a cleanout for the line.

Comment: I'm located in PA. I saw your previous posts and they were helpful but I think I misunderstood the toilet being last. So would this be correct? >> https://imgur.com/ROoV89D

Comment: @JAdamKirkpatrick Yes, that looks correct.