# Plumbing layout with many constraints

Tags: plumbing, layout

Attached is an image with constraints labeled. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to connect all this together. My best thinking so far is to run the shower with a center drain to the toilet with 2". Run the toilet out the double LVL (engineer says OK) with a 3" basically perpendicular to the West Wall into the attic space. Vent it with a new vent out the roof immediately upon exiting the double LVL (this is very close to about 5'4" from the P trap on the shower which I think is max distance... although maybe the conversion from 2" to 3" at the toilet gives me a few more inches of space to work with?). Then turn it with a long sweep 90 horizontally to go down the North side wall near the West wall of the laundry on floor 2 down to tie it into the main waste line under floor 2.

As for the vanity run a 2" waste pipe through the South wall into the attic space on the west and bring it back around and tie it into the 3" I sent down the laundry wall. I'd probably vent this immediately out of the south wall through the roof, or if code allows maybe just do an air admittance valve for the sink.

Any suggestions? How would you plumb this with all these constraints?[image]

Here is the option I'm thinking.
[image]

Comment: It might help to draw in your prospective drain and vent lines.

Comment: @FreeMan I added my thinking drawn over the image.

Comment: I don't think you can put the toilet in the middle of a wet vent in that configuration.  There are restrictions on toilets so water (e.g. from your shower) won't flow past the toilet's drain connection and cause a suction effect on the contents of the bowl.  You will probably need to install the east wall vent you have identified as an option in your drawing, or re-configure the way the shower & toilet wet vents meet -- the language the IBC uses is *symmetrical fitting* IIRC?

Comment: shower drain, to vanity drain, to main and toilet to main??

Comment: Thanks @JeffWheeler. Are you familiar with a 45 degree rolled wye? I'm guessing I'd have to do a 2" rolled wye off the shower drain, before the toilet and then run it back into the east wall and up and out? Would that cover the toilet and the shower?

Comment: @GregNickoloff I wish I could make it that easy, but there is a triple truss blocking off the vanity from the toilet/shower that I can't drill through.

Comment: I think you can choose to install the east wall vent **or** comply with the *symmetrical fitting* option (like a 3" double-wye.)  Either way the water in the shower trap & toilet shouldn't interact with each-other and get siphoned away, which I believe is the purpose of the rule.  Hopefully someone with a better understanding of the toilet rule for wet vents will chime in and clarify.  There is an older post with some diagrams https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/116736/wet-vent-distance-for-toilet-drain